# How to display Gridview according to values in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to check for the services in `TypeOfServices` according to the `ClientId`, and check for all the services.

The database Columns are `TaxId, ClientId, ClientName,TypeOfservice`

The gridview should display Client names in alphabetical order,and the services present should display 'yes' else 'no'

I used this C# code but it's not working...

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblclientname = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblclientname");

        Label lblincometax = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblincometax");
        Label lblprofessionaltax = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblprofessionaltax");
        Label lblservicetax = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblservicetax");
        Label lbltds = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltds");
        Label lblvat = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblvat");
        Label lblcompanylaw = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblcompanylaw");

        string m = "SELECT * FROM tblTaxMaster";
        ds = gs.getdata(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string ClientId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ClientId"].ToString();
                string TaxId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaxId"].ToString();

                string ser = "select TypeOfService from tblTaxMaster where ClientId= '" + ClientId.ToString() + "' and TaxId = '" + TaxId.ToString() + "' ";
                ds = gs.getdata(ser);

                if (ser == "INCOME TAX")
                {
                    lblincometax.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblincometax.Text = "NO";
                }

                if (ser == "TDS")
                {
                    lbltds.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lbltds.Text = "NO";
                }
                if (ser == "PROFESSIONAL TAX")
                {
                    lblprofessionaltax.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblprofessionaltax.Text = "NO";
                }
                if (ser == "SERVICE TAX")
                {
                    lblservicetax.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblservicetax.Text = "NO";
                }
                if (ser == "VAT")
                {
                    lblvat.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblvat.Text = "NO";
                }
                if (ser == "COMPANY LAW")
                {
                    lblcompanylaw.Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblcompanylaw.Text = "NO";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ASP.Net Code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="550px" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="10pt" 
     ShowFooter="True"   FooterStyle-BackColor="#FF5600"
    CellPadding="4" CssClass="grid-view"  PageSize="20" 
     GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                    <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Client Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblclientname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ClientName")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Income Tax">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblincometax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Professional Tax">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblprofessionaltax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Service Tax">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblservicetax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="TDS">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbltds" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="VAT">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblvat" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Company Law">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcompanylaw" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>  

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnservicedetails" runat="server" Text="Service Details" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>  



                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#333333" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#191919" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#191919" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />

                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: why can you do all the alterations in a datatable and bind it to gridview..?

Comment: post code related to getdata() method

Comment: What error you are getting or what output your are getting?

Comment: one thing need to "is your if condition is right?" as "ser" is you command and every time condition will result false. And more importantly your your first SQL statement returns all rows of the table you need to set some condition for each row of database to be equal with gridview row.

Answer (score 0):

Why are looping if you are already getting the required values from

```
SELECT * FROM tblTaxMaster
```

When bind the gridview use joins and get the TypeOfService value in the select statement only  and then modify your source code to

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Client Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblclientname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ClientName")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Income Tax">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblincometax" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("typeOfService")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Not working means...? are u able to update the alternate rows label text's....because in IF conditiona u should write something like if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.AlternateDataRow)

Comment: The Label in the Gridview should read 'yes' if the service is present in Database for that particular client. I do not want the value of column. 
E.g. If For client ABC if services are IncomeTax then the Client name should read as ABC and GridView inside label of Income Tax should Read 'yes' and rest 'No'.

Comment: You didnt read my comment properly....try explaining ur issue properly otherwise no one can solve